# Mode of Convergence and Topology

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I am trying to learn different modes of convergence of random variables in probability space. I see on Wikipedia that: $\textbf{Convergence in probability defines a topology on the space of random variables}$

What is the topology here explicitly? And can someone please give a proof of the statement?

Comment: The next line on the Wikipedia article states that this is the topology induced by the Ky Fan metric, and states a reference to Dudley (2002).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rather verbose explanation to the question:

- The space of (finite) real measurable functions (denote it by $\mathcal{L}_0(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbf{P})$) on $\Omega$ is a vector space (in fact, it is a vector lattice but that does not matter at the moment).
- It it *natural* to ask if there is an interesting topology that makes $\mathcal{L}_0$ a linear topological space. This is a old question and here is one way to introduce a topology: 
  $$
  \|f\|_0:=\inf\{\varepsilon>0: \mathbb{P}[|f|>\varepsilon]\leq\varepsilon\}
  $$
- This *gauge* has some nice properties which are easy to check: For all $f,g\in L_0$ and $r\in\mathbb{R}$,

  1. $\mathbb{P}[|f|>\|f\|_0]\leq\|f\|_0\leq1$.
  2. $\|f+g\|_0\leq\|f\|_0+\|g\|_0$.
  3. $\|f\|_0\leq\|g\|_0$ if $|f|\leq |g|$.
  4. $\|rf\|_0\leq (r\vee1)\|f\|_0$.
  5. $\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\|rf\|_0=0$.
  6. $\|f\|_0=0$ iff $\mathbb{P}[|f|>0]=0$, i.e. iff $f=0$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.
- $\|\cdot\|_0$ is not a norm, and $d_0(f,g)=\|f-g\|_0$ is a pseudometric.
- Identifying $f$ and $g$ whenever $|f-g|=0$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s., we obtained a metric space $(L_0,d_0)$ which can be seen to be in fact a topological vector space, that is sum $(f,g)\mapsto f+g$ and scalar product $(r,f)\mapsto rf$ are continuous functions on $(L_0,d_0)\times(L_0,d_0)$ and $(\mathbb{R},|\;|)\times(L_0,d_0)$ respectively.
- It is easy to check that on $(L_0,d_0)$, $d_0(f_n,f)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ iff $\lim_n\mathbb{P}[|f_n-f|>\varepsilon]=0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$.
- The space $(L_0,d_0)$, or rather the topology generated by $d_0$ is what is called the topology of convergence in probability.

---

There are other ways (more common in textbooks on measure-theoretic probability) to introduce convergence in probability as a concept first, and then to represent it with a metric on $L_0$.

- For example: given $\varepsilon>0$ and (finite) random variables $X$ and $Y$
  $$
  \varepsilon\mathbb{1}_{\{|X-Y|>\epsilon\}}\leq |X-Y|\wedge 1 \leq \varepsilon +\mathbb{1}_{\{|X-Y|>\varepsilon\}}
  $$
  Hence
  $$
  \varepsilon\mathbb{P}[|X-Y|>\varepsilon]\leq \mathbb{E}[|X-Y|\wedge1]\leq \varepsilon+\mathbb{P}[|X-Y|>\varepsilon]
  $$
  So a sequence $X_n$  convergence in probability to $X$, i.e., $\lim_n\mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|>\varepsilon]=0$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, if and only if $\lim_n\mathbb{E}[|X_n-X|\wedge1]=0$.

The map $(X,Y)\mapsto\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|\wedge1]$ defines a metric on $L_0$. It is also easy to check that $d$ and $d_0$ are equivalent, that is they generate the same open sets.

---

An important point is that while the classical $L_p$ ($p\geq1$) spaces are complete normed spaces, $L_0$ is not normable in general, an may  even failed to locally convex;mfor instance, the $L_0$ on the set $((0,1)$ with Lebesgue's measure is not locally convex. However common metrics  make $(L_0,d)$ a nice  topological vector space; furthermore, it has practical applications not only in Probability theory but also in Statistics.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a great answer!

Comment: Your welcome. Notice that I fixed a false statement that I made towards the end related to the local convexity (or lack of it) in general $L_0$ spaces and the normality of them.